# How to remove iPhone app via command line

Tags: iphone, command-line, jailbreak

I would like to uninstall my app through the command line, and i have no idea how to do it, i find someone said the below command can do it:

1. In Mac Terminal, SSH into your iPhone ssh -l root 10.0.1.4 [password] cd /Applications/xxx.app rm *.* cd ../ rmdir xxx.app exit
2. Restart iPhone. Application widget should be gone, no longer appearing on the Springboard.

but in my phone, i just find that my app is not in the path "/Applications/", so anybody can give me some help, thanks in advance.

---

Thanks rjstelling, i know the iFile can do such thing, but what i want is to remove my app through the command line, now i do it using an unsmart method, just find my app in /var/mobile/Applications, then delete the dir who contain it, you know all this can be done through command, i hope i can find a better idea to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to delete an application downloaded from an App Store you can do so right in the Springboard (on your iPhone). If you can't do that, you can delete it in a folder (/private)/var/mobile/Applications/ there are apps installed from App Store or synced. (in /Applications/ you will find Cydia, Camera, Safari, etc...)

To do so, you will first have to find out what is the "hashed" name of the Applications in that folder, because you won't find "InfinityBlade.app" in there, you will find some random letters and numbers.

You can also delete it by installing a program called iFile from the Cydia and then by checking in the settings "Show application names" or something like that and then again by going to (/private)/var/mobile/Applications/ where you should see now the real name of the applications and then simply delete it by the gesture "slide from left to right with your finger" and click delete.

Hope this works for you, it should work 100% ;-)

**Update:** *This is a link where is sort of described what I meant with the iFile, just don't go into /var/stash/Applications but /var/mobile/Applications*
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftssbPYiBDw

Comment: You can always go to `/private/var/mobile/Applications/` and use the command `find . -name Dropbox.app` or `find . -name Dropbox*` to locate the folder

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is allowed to (perhaps installing cydelete will give you apt-get if you cant use it) you may be able to use

> sudo apt-get remove [your app]